# Setting up a local high score?

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I am setting up a local high score for a game in unity 3d where, for every second that passes, you gain +1 point.

Right now I have this script set up on an empty game object so I can display the points in real time, but when you die and the game goes back to the menu scene how do I then load your previous score and your highest score, into the menu scene? I have looked many places and cant find a valid option that helps me, also pretty new to unity but I have a mild understanding of js, will also take C# but more comfortable with js. Do I need an object set up in the menu pulling data from MainGame scene? Been struggling on this one for a while.

```
var textfield : GUIText;
static var score : int; 

function Start()
{
    score = 0;
}

function Update()
{
    score = Time.timeSinceLevelLoad;        
    UpdateScoreText();                  
}

function UpdateScoreText()
{
    textfield.text = score.ToString();    
}
```

Comment: Does this data need to persist after leaving the application, or do you not care if it gets wiped when users quit the app?

Comment: @DakotahHicock I would prefer that it saves the highest score so that the user may continue trying to beat it the next time the app is opened.

Comment: No idea how unity works but if I understand correctly, you want to save some scores so you can use them later? How about saving to a text file? If that is possible in unity.

Comment: @Andre saving to a text file would be great however I believe that file would get deleted once a new scene (level) opens.

Comment: Get the data. Play the game. Check to see what new scores should be. Save new scores. Just dont write to the file if scores didnt change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most obvious way for this and the easiest is using the [playerprefs](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html).
u can just save the value and then load from anywhere you like even if you close the game and reopen it.

ex:
Saving)

```
PlayerPrefs.SetString("the string Title", "the text you want to save");
```

Loading)

```
print (PlayerPrefs.GetString("the string Title"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Set it up so that when they die, the data is saved somewhere.

You can store this any number of ways in C#. You can use a text file as the easiest method, but it can be altered with a text editor, so keep that in mind.

Comment: I guess I don't know how to go about storing the data, and if it will be different in android and ios, again not the best with c# but if i had something to go off of I could probably figure it out. I will continue searching.

Comment: With iOS, you can use CoreData to store this. With Android, you should be able to use SqlLite/OrmData. You also can save a .txt file to the app folder and update as needed. The .txt file is probably more work than necessary for this situation in my opinion.